# Google Maps Elevation license

Tags: google-maps, elevation, google-maps-api-3, google-elevation-api

I would like to use [Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start) to query elevation data for my future free and open source script.

What I would like to know is what is the exact text which I need to include in my license documentation in order to provide the appropriate credit to Google corporation, for using their Google Maps Elevation API?

I checked [Google Maps API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#2-accepting-the-terms) page, but I didn't understand which text to include to my license documentation.

Where can I find this info?

I tried [contacting Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/) directly, but never got a reply from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the [terms and conditions further](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/policies), to quote

> The Google Maps Elevation API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map. It is prohibited to use Google Maps Elevation API data without displaying a Google map.

If you're willing to accept that limitation, that page provides the info on giving credit.

As an alternative, [Mapzen have a similar service](https://mapzen.com/documentation/elevation/elevation-service/) - not tried this, but looks like it might do what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Steven Kay. It's very useful!!
Seems like I missed that part about Google Maps Elevation API being tied to Google Maps. Thank you also for pointing out the Mapzen alternative!

Do you know where the exact license text could be found for the Google Maps Elevation API? The text that needs to be included to license documentation/page?